# MATLABs fitgmdist function in 1 dimension

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, gaussian

I have previously posted this on the [Mathworks Community](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/434387-using-fitgmdist-on-a-histogram), but am reposting here for a wider audience...

I have a 1 dimensional Histogram, to which I want to fit gaussians:

[image]

In the above example I need to find the centres of the 4 dominant peaks, however, the number of peaks may vary in a different Histogram.
Below is a MWE of my approach:

```
bins = 2000;
fsc_hist = histogram(FSC_data.FSC_HF,bins);hold on;
%% smooth data to get rid of discretization
fscValues = fsc_hist.Values;
binStep = (fsc_hist.BinLimits(2)-fsc_hist.BinLimits(1))/fsc_hist.NumBins;
binCenters =  binStep * [0:fsc_hist.NumBins-1];
smoothValues = smooth(binCenters, fscValues, 0.1, 'rloess');
%% fit GMM
expectedPeaks = 4;
gmm = fitgmdist(smoothValues, expectedPeaks, 'RegularizationValue', 0.1);
```

Which returns the following GMM result:

> Gaussian mixture distribution with 4 components in 1 dimensions
>
> Component 1: Mixing proportion: 0.294734 Mean:    0.2417
>
> Component 2: Mixing proportion: 0.152275 Mean:   41.9369
>
> Component 3: Mixing proportion: 0.344658 Mean:    6.8231
>
> Component 4: Mixing proportion: 0.208333 Mean:   24.6758

Obviously, the calculated Mean values of the gaussians is not correct.
**Where is my approach going wrong?** I believe that either my first input to the `fitgmdist` function must somehow be normalised, or that I need to post-process the output. So far, my attempts have failed.

Comment: If you use `histcounts` instead of `histogram` then it will output the bin edges for you (2nd output), makes life easier!

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that the mixing models is giving you the means of Gaussian distributions of the counts. Instead of inputting the histogram into fitgmdist, you should input the raw FSC_data.FSC_HF data into the first argument.

Comment: thanks for your answer! The raw FSC_HF data is a vector of size 1x28497 (i.e. = to the sum of counts of each bin). I don't see how that would make sense as there is no structure to this vector... it is just a 'random' sequence of numbers. Fitting a GMM to this would result non-sense. Either way, I have tried out your suggestion: without any luck.
I can't say that I understnd what exactly fitgmdist expects as first input... It seems to me that I would need to supply both the bin centres (as x-vector) as well as the bin counts (as y-vector) to which fitgmdist can then fit the curve...

Comment: The Matlab program processes the data using the expectation-maximization algorithm (EM) which presumably does not require the histogram counts as inputs. Another method, which may achieve similar results for your aims is to threshold the distribution (maybe once to split it into two and one more for each split to return 4 distributions). You could then find the means of each of the four distributions.